# Applicative parser example in Scala

Tags: scala, parsing, scalaz, applicative

This is a new version of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675240/how-to-define-for-applicative-parser)

We can define a parser as `type Parser[A] = String => List[(A, String)]`. The parser takes an input string and yields a sequence of pairs. Each pair consists of the parsing result and unconsumed part of the input. (See more in this [article](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/237/1/monparsing.pdf))

Now we can define a parser `pa`, which succeeds if the 1st input character is `a` and fails otherwise.

```
def symbol(c: Char): Parser[Char] = {s: String => 
  s.toList match { case x :: xs if x == c => List((x, xs.mkString)); case _ => Nil } 
}

val pa = symbol('a')
```

We can also define `map` and `flatMap` for `Parser[A]` and then use them to compose parsers:

```
val pa = symbol('a')
val pb = symbol('b')
val pab: Parser[(Char, Char)] = for (a <- pa; b <- pa) yield (a, b)
```

It is [turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080979/why-is-parser-combinator-seq-defined-with-bind-and-return) though that we can compose parsers with `<*>` too.

> An example of an applicative parser. Suppose we want to recognise nested parentheses and compute the maximum nesting depth. The grammar S -> (S)S | epsilon describes this structure, which is directly reflected in the parser.

```
pS = (max . (+1)) <$ pSym '(' <*> pS <* pSym ')' <|> pure 0
```

Unfortunately I can't get my head around this example. So my questions are:

- How to define `<*>` for parsers ? (not with `flatMap`) ?
- How to translate this example to Scala (with `scalaz`) ?

Answer (score 1):

`<*>` (terrible name) apparently has this signature:

```
<*>[B](f: F[(A) ⇒ B]): F[B]
```

So let's just chase the types through, thinking about what a parser should do - helped by the fact that `List` already implements `flatMap`:

```
def <*>[A, B](fa: Parser[A], fab: Parser[(A) => B]) =
  new Parser[B] {
    def apply(s: String) =
      for {
        (a, rem1) ← fa(s)
        (ab, rem2) ← fab(rem1)
      } yield (ab(a), rem2)
  }
```

That looks like a sensible implementation - parse `a` first, then parse `ab` from the remainder, and then we have our result.

That example is too symbolic for me and I don't know Haskell - if you can find documentation for the `<$` and `<|>` then I'll give it a go.

Comment: Yes, this is a trivial implementation of `<*>` in terms of `flatMap`, meaning that any monad is an applicative (in Haskell/Scala). Unfortunately it seems tautological to me. That's why I wrote: `"How to define <*> for parsers ? (not with flatMap)"`. I should have probably made it more clear but thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: I thought you meant not using `Parser`'s `flatMap` as it's just equivalent? Of course any monad is an applicative, by definition; it *should* be the same implementation. Do you want me to spell out the implementation of `List.flatMap`? I can do that but I don't think it would be very enlightening.

Comment: I meant such a `<*>`, which was _different_ from the `<*>` based on `flatMap`.  The latter is not the only possible implementation of `<*>`. For example, we can define two different `<*>` for `List`.

Comment: But that's the `<*>` we would want for parsers, isn't it? What other semantics would we want `<*>` to have?

Comment: I don't know. I am still thinking about such cases when parsers don't depend on the parser, which run earlier (fixed CVS records maybe ?). For those cases I will probably need the different `<*>`.